# Why is a WorkingDirectory with spaces problematic for systemd? (Valheim Dedicated Server)

Tags: systemd

In the following service, if I leave out the `WorkingDirectory` entry entirely, systemd can parse the file, but the service itself needs `WorkingDirectory` set. However, whenever it is set to this particular directory, I get:

```
$ systemctl --user start valheim.service
Failed to start valheim.service: Unit valheim.service has a bad unit file setting.
```

I verified the directory as shown is correct and exists.

Here's the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Valheim Server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=False
WorkingDirectory="/home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Valheim dedicated server"
ExecStart="/home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Valheim dedicated server/start_emerlain.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I also tried using `systemd-escape`:

```
$ systemd-escape --path "/home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Valheim dedicated server"
home-brandon-.local-share-Steam-steamapps-common-Valheim\x20dedicated\x20server
```

Then changed to:

```
WorkingDirectory=home-brandon-.local-share-Steam-steamapps-common-Valheim\x20dedicated\x20server
```

(also tried with double quotes, but no luck).

Digging for more details using the suggested approach seems to [encounter difficulties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328245/how-to-fix-systemctl-status-not-working-as-non-root-user-in-20-04-upgrade):

```
$ systemctl --user status valheim.service
Failed to parse bus message: No such device or address
```

**Edit 1**

I forgot to mention that setting `WorkingDirectory="/home/brandon"`, for example, does not cause the same issue - systemd seems to accept this simpler directory.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it is a bug in systemd that has since been fixed. I got it to work with the following workaround using /usr/bin/env on RHEL 8. I changed it to match your username etc. You should be able to use double or single quotes for paths with spaces in later versions of systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=Valheim service
Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
User=brandon
WorkingDirectory=/home/brandon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env -C "/home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Valheim dedicated server/" "/home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Valheim dedicated server/start_server.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```